# Colouring datagrid rows

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I was wondering how to colour the first 8 rows of a datagridview. I have managed to sort the values in descending order and I wish to have the first 8 rows coloured to highlight the top 8 to the user, and I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

```
Dim count As Integer
For count = 0 To datagridsort.RowCount - 1
  Do
    datagridsort.Rows(0).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.Coral
    datagridsort.Rows(0).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Coral
  Loop Until count = 8
Next
```

Comment: Loop through them: `dgv.Rows(x).Cells(y).Style.BackColor = Color.Red`

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted in your comment, you were never using the *count* variable.  You were only updated the first row every time.  Try it like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Math.Min(datagridsort.RowCount - 1, 7)
  For j As Integer = 0 To datagridsort.ColumnCount - 1
    datagridsort.Rows(i).Cells(j).Style.BackColor = Color.Coral
  Next
Next
```

Comment: @das_l Did you forget to use the i & j variables.  Your code was using `datagridsort.Rows(0)...` where you were only updating Rows(0).  My post is doing Rows(i).

Comment: @das_l Well, run this code *after* you add rows.  Alternatively, you can play with the RowsAdded event to make this work, too.

Comment: I have just implemented the code after the rows are added and it works! Thank you so so so much for this! You have helped me so much and I can now move on to the next part of my code! thank you thank you thank you!!